# Create an object on method

Tags: go

It is a bad code when I create a self obeject on the method? Like this(Look at the method Create)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type SelfInitialisator struct {
    Fields1, Fields2 string
}

func (rcv *SelfInitialisator) Method1() {
    fmt.Println(rcv.Fields1, rcv.Fields2)
}

func (rcv *SelfInitialisator) CreateObject() {
    s := new(SelfInitialisator)
    s.Fields1 = "Hello"
    s.Fields2 = "Foo"
}

func main() {

    s := new(SelfInitialisator)
    s.CreateObject()

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code you are creating a memory object, then throwing it away and creating another one which is rather inefficient.  You also aren't returning it.

```
s := new(SelfInitialisator)
s.CreateObject()
```

The Go way would be to use a function to create your object, like this

```
func NewSelfInitialisator() *SelfInitialisator {
    s := new(SelfInitialisator)
    s.Fields1 = "Hello"
    s.Fields2 = "Foo"
    return s
}
```

And call

```
s := NewSelfInitialisator()
```

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't mutate the receiver, only create another instance which would be lost at the end of CreateObject() call.
You could use the receiver directly to initialize its content:

```
func (rcv *SelfInitialisator) CreateObject() {
    rcv.Fields1 = "Hello"
    rcv.Fields2 = "Foo"
}
```

Comment: What I want to do is with ServeHTTP as follow https://gist.github.com/kostonstyle/665f442703c29ef4dff1. As you can see on the ServeHTTP method, it creates the own(controller) object like in a class based language, when I create an object on the static method.